# php: Create array with ojects or how to get rid off extra quotes symbols

Tags: php, json

I store some data in file, that looks like this

```
{"name":"name1","uuid":"uuid1"}
{"name":"name2","uuid":"uuid2"}
```

than with php I convert it to JSON with next code

```
$file = "someData.json";
$content = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($file));

$output = array( 'someData' => array_values( array_filter($content) ) );

$output = json_encode($output);
echo $output;
```

in output i get object

```
[ " {"name":"name1","uuid":"uuid1"},{"name":"name2","uuid":"uuid2"} " ]
```

instead of array with objects

```
[{"name":"name1","uuid":"uuid1"},{"name":"name2","uuid":"uuid2"}]
```

What is the best solution to get array with objects or just o delete those first and last quote sybols?

Comment: You want `json_decode`, not `json_encode`.

Comment: @Graham I use that output in ajax call, so finaly i need a json array with objects

Comment: You're opening a file containing JSON, then you need to `json_decode` it to get it in PHP, then you want to `json_encode` it again to send it out as JSON... Seems an odd thing to do to me, but in what you've described you need to `json_decode` the contents of `$file` before you process any of it with PHP.

Comment: I wouldn't say its odd!  Turn json to PHP (json_decode)...operate on the php (the array filter)...then php-to-json (json_encode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for helping. I'm not so good in php but even after getting rid of errors in your examples I make other decision. Now I echo pure JSON without any decoding/encoding in such primitive way:

```
$file = "file.json";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = rtrim($content, ",\r\n");

$output = '
        {
            "someData": ['.$someData.']
        }
        ';
```

Answer (score 2):

The comment under your question is correct.  You are ignoring the step to decode the json into PHP data structures, so each of your javascript objects are merely being treated as strings, not as the objects/hashes you want to treat them as.

Rather than exploding the way you are, rewrite it to look like:

> $file = file_get_contents("someData.json";)
> $content = json_decode($file);
>
> $output = array( 'someData' => array_values( array_filter($content));
>
> $output = json_encode($output);
> echo $output;

Answer (score 1):

I know this may look stupid but it does work using a preg replace.

```
$json = '[ " {"name":"name1","uuid":"uuid1"},{"name":"name2","uuid":"uuid2"} " ]";

preg_replace(array("/[ \" {/", "/} \" ]/"), array("[{", "}]"), $json);
```

Comment: Though I love the creativity, why would you recommend using PCRE over a built in JSON-compatible decoder that handles json-to-php translation? PCRE can be dog slow sometimes, and I would trust the performance of the json function over it almost any day!

Comment: I answered this question with a solution to the problem, I know it's not the best solution and if I had the same problem I wouldn't use it either.

Comment: Fair enough!  I just wondered if there was a particular usecase for the preg solution, or if it was just the first thing to come to mind.

Comment: It just seemed like the easiest and fastest option to delete those first and last quote sybols.